# How to connect opensearch dashboard to elasticsearch cluster?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, opensearch, opensearch-dashboards

I am trying to connect opensearch dashboard to elasticsearch cluster to replace kibana inorder to use ldap, Is there a way to achieve this?

I tried connecting to elasticsearch from opensearch dashboard but i was getting incompatible issues
`This version of OpenSearch Dashboards (v1.3.11) is incompatible with the following OpenSearch nodes in your cluster: v7.15.2`

Answer (score 0):

Since 7.10.2, OpenSearch and Elasticsearch are two different and diverging products.

OpenSearch Dashboards can only connect to an OpenSearch cluster, the same way Kibana can only connect to Elasticsearch and not OpenSearch.